# asp.net session timeout don't occuring

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, session-state, session-timeout

My web.config have this system.web section:

```html
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, &#xA;Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, &#xA;Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, &#xA;PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages theme="Padrao" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagPrefix="rsweb" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <sessionState timeout="1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="2097151" />
  </system.web>
```

But in my application, the session never expire.
I can always get the session variable values.

What am I forgetting in the configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the source code of the system has not setting the 
Session.Timeout value.

Or use this:
**

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="1"/>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="1"  />
</system.web>
```

**

Comment: Didn't work.When I go to the next page, I still can get the value inside the session variables.